# Find an orthogonal vector with a specific property in a 2n-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-algebras

Suppose $\mathbb{v}_1\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $\mathbb{v}_2\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are two vectors. Consider a hyperplane $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ space that is perpendicular to $(\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2})$, so that for any vector $\mathbf{z}$ in $P$ we have $\mathbf{z}.(\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2})=0$. Now assume $C$ is the intersection of the hyperplane $P$ with $(\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2})$. So the vector $\mathbf{w}=OC$ is also perpendicular to $(\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2})$. I want to rotate the vector $\mathbf{w}$ on the hyperplane $P$ with a rotation angle $\alpha$ to find vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ (so $\boldsymbol{\theta}.(\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2})=0$). How can I find the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$? Can I do the rotation with matrix operation?

Additional comment; $P$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2$ and passes through the origin.

Comment: Let me be more clear about this problem:

I found $\mathbf{w}=[w_1,w_2,\dots,w_{2n}]$ as:
$$w_{i}=\frac{1}{\left\Vert \mathbf{v}_{1}-\mathbf{v}_{2}\right\Vert _{2}^{2}}\left(v_{1}^{(i)}\left(-\mathbf{v}_{2}.(\mathbf{v}_{1}-\mathbf{v}_{2})\right)+v_{2}^{(i)}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}.(\mathbf{v}_{1}-\mathbf{v}_{2})\right)\right).$$
But I need to find the vector $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ which is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2$ and has the property that $$\theta_i^2+\theta_{n+i}^2=1,\; \mathrm{for}\; i=1,\dots,n.$$
So, I want to know if there is any relation between $\boldsymbol\theta$ and $\mathbf{w}$? Can I find $\boldsymbol\theta$ from $\mathbf{w}$?

Comment: I do not see why your vector $\bf w$ should be orthogonal to $\bf{v_1 - v_2}
$

Comment: $P$ pass through the origin

Comment: Just clarifying; By "cross point" do you mean the intersection of $P$ with the line through $v_1$ and $v_2$? And by "rotate ... on the hyperplane" what plane of rotation and what center of rotation are you choosing? (You may be aware of this, but high-dimensional rotations do not generalize 2- and 3-dimensional rotations in the way many people expect.)

Comment: I updated the problem, can you please help me to find any solution?

Comment: $\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$ It doesn't "intersect" hyperplane $P$ at any particular "point". However, since $\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}$ is orthogonal to $P$, both $\mathbf{v_1}$ and $\mathbf{v_2}$ project orthogonally onto the same vector in $P$. Is this $\mathbf w$? I am still trying to parse through your formula for $\mathbf w$.

Comment: Yes, I think we can say $\mathbf{w}$ is the projection of $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ on $P$

Comment: If $P$ is a hyperplane orthgonal to $\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}$ and $\mathbf w$ is a vector in $P,$ then $\mathbf w \cdot (\mathbf{v_1}-\mathbf{v_2}) = 0,$ so you don't need to rotate at all.

Comment: The condition on the components of $\theta$ suggests you're really in a complex $n$-dimensional vector space, and are seeking a complex vector whose components are unit...? But like DavidK I'm still struggling to understand the substance of the question; particularly, it's not obvious to me what $\theta$ is: that such a vector exists and is unique.

Comment: @DavidK I know $\mathbf{w}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2$, I need to find $\boldsymbol\theta$. I might have been wrong about the rotation problem, so I updated the problem. Is there any relation between $\boldsymbol\theta$ and $\mathbf{w}$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, Yes, you are right, it's in a complex n-dimensional vector space. There is a solution to this problem (I solved it in a different way, refer to https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9855413 - Section III). But I need to understand it from a geometrical viewpoint. It is essential for me.

Comment: Ah, I was distracted by the angle $\alpha$ and missed the condition on $\boldsymbol\theta$ near the end of the question. Doesn't that condition ensure that $\lVert\boldsymbol\theta\rVert^2=n$? So how do we ensure that this is a rotation and not a scaling of $\mathbf w$? I looked at Section III of your linked paper briefly and it wasn't instantly obvious how your question relates to it except for the final condition on $\boldsymbol\theta$.

Comment: If it's scaling, then $w_i^2+w_{n+i}^2=k$

Comment: In the paper, I want to find a $\boldsymbol\theta=[\boldsymbol\theta^R , \boldsymbol\theta^I]$ to maximize both $\mathbf{v}_1.\boldsymbol\theta$ and $\mathbf{v}_2.\boldsymbol\theta$, where $\mathbf{v}_1=[\mathbf{h}_m^R, -\mathbf{h}_m^I ]=[A,C]$ and $\mathbf{v}_2=[\mathbf{h}_n^I, -\mathbf{h}_n^R]=[B,D] $. A max-min problem was defined and $\boldsymbol\theta$ is found by solving the problem (Eqs. 28 and 29, where $\lambda_1$ is the solution for Eq. 27).

Comment: Finally, it can be proved that $\mathbf{v}_1.\boldsymbol\theta=\mathbf{v}_2.\boldsymbol\theta$, so $\boldsymbol\theta$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{v}_2$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang; thanks for your comments. Additional important comment: The vector $\boldsymbol\theta$ exists and is unique due to the specific properties of $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$; all of their elements are random and follow normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1/2)$, so Eq. 27 has only one solution for $\lambda_1$.